# jQuery, multi tabs referencing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to track use idle time, so that after x minutes, I show a count down counter,
the issue is not here, but, imagine this scenario:

the user opened tab A and tab B,
if the user got idle at tab A for x minutes, the count down counter will be shown, but, if the user shown any activity at tab B, I need to hide the count down counter at tab A.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean tabs in a jQuery UI tab control, or browser tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the timer on each tab after it's clicked.  How are you showing two open tabs at the same time anyway?